# graph = Graph(g) NameError: name 'Graph' is not defined.COMO LO RESUELVO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2.x, python-requests

```
    introducir el código#TAD DE DIJKSTRA, algoritmo de caminos mínimos.
#es un algoritmo para la determinación del camino más corto.
#dado un vértice origen.
#hacia el resto de los vértices en un grafo que tiene pesos en cada arista.
####################################
#ninguna de las libreria se me importan bien

import sys
import heapq
#from Grafo import graph NO SE IMPORTA BIEN
from matrizAdyacencia import matrizAdyacencia
sys.path.insert(0,'C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Desktop\\AED2PRO.AVION\\Javier\\Grafo')


def Dijkstra(aGraph,start):
    pq=PriorytyQueue()
    start.setdistance(a)
    pq.buildHeap([(v.getdistance(),v)for v in aGraph])
    while not pq is empty():
        currentvert=pq.delMin()
        for nextvert in currentvert.getconections():
            newdist=currentvert.getdistance+currentvert.getweight(nextvert)
            if newdist<nextvert.getdistance():
                nextvert.setdistance(newdist)
                nextvert.setpred(currentvert)
                pq.decreasekey(nextvert,newdist)


def heapsort(iterable):
    h=[]
    for value in iterable:
        heapush(h,value)
    return [heapop(h)for i in range (len(h))]

graph = Graph(g)

mAdy = matrizAdyacencia(graph)

#Muestro la matriz de adyacencia
for x in mAdy:
    print(x)


g={ 'a' : ['d'],
    'b' : ['c'],
    'c' : ['b','d','e'],
    'd' : ['a','c'],
    'e' : ['c'],
    'f' : []
}

#################################################
aca va el de matriz de adyacencia
"""
    matrizAdyacencia crea la matriz de adyacencia del grafo que se le pase
    como parámetro y la devuelve.
    El archivo que llame a esta función debe importar primero la clase Graph.
"""
def matrizAdyacencia(G):
    """
        Precondiciones: un grafo de la clase Graph
        Postcondiciones: devuelve la matriz de adyacencia del grafo
    """
    v = len(G.vertices())
    #Creo una matriz de ceros con las dimensiones NroVertices x NroVertices
    matriz = [[0 for y in range(v)] for y in range(v)]
    x=0
    y=0
    #Recorro el diccionario del grafo para encontrar los adyacentes de cada vertice
    for key1 in G._graph_dict.keys():
        #Lista con los adyacentes de "key1" (key1 itera por los vertices)
        lista = G._graph_dict[key1]
        for key2 in G._graph_dict.keys():
            if key2 in lista:
                #Es adyacente de "key1"
                matriz[x][y] = 1
            else:
                #No es adyacente de "key1"
                matriz[x][y] = 0
            y+=1
        x+=1
        y=0
    return matriz
#############################################################
 #tad de grafo
#TAD DE GRAFOS
#El grafo en python se representa en diccionario
class Graph(object):
    def __ini__(self,graph_dict=None):
        if graph_dict==None:
            #CREO UN DICCIONARIO VACIO
            graph_dict={}
            #SI NO ESTA VACIO DEVUELVE EL GRAFO
            self._graph_dict=graph_dict

    """se retorna en las dos siguientes funciones los vertices y las aristas"""
    def vertices(self):
        return list(self._graph_dict.keys())

    def edges(self):
        return self._generate_edges()

    def add_vertex(self,vertex):
        if vertex not in self._graph_dict:
            self._graph_dict[vertex]=[]
    def add_edges(self,edges):
        edge=set(edge)
        (vertex1,vertex2)=tuple(edge)
        if vertex1 in self._graph_dict:
            self._graph_dict[vertex1].append(vertex2)
        else:
            self._graph_dict[vertex1]=[vertex2]

    def _generate_edges(self):
        edge=[]
        for vertex in self._graph_dict:
            for neighbour in self._graph_dict[vertex]:
                if{neighbour,vertex} not in edges:
                    edges.append({vertex,neighbour})
        return edges
    def __str__(self):
        res="vertices:"
        for k in self._graph_dict:
            res=str(k)+ ""
        res+= "\n edges: "
        for edge in self._generate_edges():
            res+=str(edges)+""
        return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #---------------------------------Implementación de funciones básicas---------------------------------#
    # Creo el grafo con un diccionario
    # Lo que esta a la derecha de los ':' son los vértices
    # Lo que esta a la izquierda de los ':' entre '[]' son las listas de adyacencias de esos vértices
    g={ 'a' : ['d'],
        'b' : ['c'],
        'c' : ['b','c','d','e'], # 'c' tiene un ciclo porque se repite en su lista de adyacencia
        'd' : ['a','c'],
        'e' : ['c'],
        'f' : [] # 'f' es un vértice aislado porque no tiene nada en su lista de adyacencia
    }

    """# Instancio el objeto pasandole como parámetro el grafo que cree anteriormente
    print("Implementación de funciones básicas:")
    graph = Graph(g)
    print("1) Vertices del grafo: ")
    print(graph.vertices()) # Imprimo los vertices
    print("2) Aristas del grafo: ")
    print(graph.edges()) # Imprimo las aristas
    print("3) Agrego un vertice 'z': ")
    graph.add_vertex("z")
    print("- Vertices del grafo: ")
    print(graph.vertices())
    print("4) Agrego una arista {'a','z'}: ")
    graph.add_edge({"a","z"})
    print("- Aristas del grafo: ")
    print(graph.edges())
    # Ahora intento agregar aristas con vértices que no existen
    print("5) Agregando una arista {'x','y'} con nuevos vertices: ")
    graph.add_edge({"x","y"})
    print("- Vertices: ")
    print(graph.vertices())
    print("- Aristas: ")
    print(graph.edges())
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    """
```

aquí

Comment: Hola Javier, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para que la pregunta sea de calidad y podamos ayudarte, has de explicar lo que pretendes ( los datos que introduces y el resultado esperado y el algoritmo Dijkstra que no se tiene por qué conocer) asi como lo que te sucede actualmente: errores, problemas ? No podemos depurar por tí. MIra  [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: graph = Graph(g)
NameError: name 'Graph' is not defined
ese error me da

Comment: Lee los enlaces (el [tour] no lo has completado) y pulsa en [edit] para añadir ese comentario y la **demás** informacion necesaria para la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Has de mejorar tambien tu pregunta anterior segun lo que te explican en los comentarios

Comment: Javier deberías editar la pregunta para delimitar que pertenece a cada módulo, es decir "En Grafo.py tengo esto: código..." además de agregar el error. Primero de todo, si agregas una ruta vía `sys.path` debes agregarla **antes** de intentar importar los módulos causantes de que la agregues o el import lógicamente fallará. De todas formas, si agregas la **estructura de tu proyecto mostrando dónde está localizado cada módulo en relación a los otros**  es posible que te podamos indicar una mejor forma de importar o estructurarlo.